# Recover Linux ext4 partition formatted to hfs+

Tags: linux, osx, data-recovery, ext4

I have a Linux partition formatted to ext4 and I accidentally formatted it with Mac OS X Disk Utility to HFS+ (Mac OS X Extended Journaled).

I tried to recover it with http://www.r-studio.com/ on Windows but I can't get any files except few from trash or temporary browser files.

Now I'm trying another software on OS X: http://www.stellarinfo.com/mac-data-recovery.htm, however it takes some time to scan partitions.

Any ideas how to recover that partition? Should I recover it on Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have any knowledge of the tool you are using, but I used before UFSexplorer and it was good (take a look [here](http://www.ufsexplorer.com/index.php?lang=curr))

Now, if you managed with the tool r-studio to get some files that's good, it means that the HFS+ format didn't wipe your disk and prepared it's initial data struture,

So, you can use UFS explorer or the software you are using from stellarinfo (although I dont' see that support ext4 ). And if it is slow it is normal. Basically, the softwares has to scan your whole HDD and identify which block belongs to which file.

Also, don't expect 100% of data retrieval, for sure some data is gone by now.

Comment: With r-studio it found all partitions, in addition it find out old partition type but it couldn't restore it

With stellar phoenix it found all partitions but nothing to do with that reformatted

Answer (score 0):

Wild guess but I would assume the platform with the most familiarity with ext4 would be your best bet (i.e. Linux).